# Apache on Centos 6.5 cant access a mounted network directory

Tags: apache, centos

I am having trouble getting Apache access to a network share that I have mounted using fstab. I am trying to learn Apache by building an image server. The script parsing all of the images can access the mounted directories and I can see thumbnails on the webpage from the browser however if I try to get a link directly to the images then it claims it doesn't have access.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: All users have rw- access. :p

I ran a `ll` on the box before and after mounting the drives and got this

```
Before Mounting: drwxrwxrwx. 2 root apache 4096 Oct 24 19:20 TestFolder
After Mounting:  drwxrwxrw-+ 4 173754 171535    0 Feb 24  2007 TestFolder
```

This is my fstab command to mount the drive on boot

```
<network drive> <local mount point> cifs username=*******,password=*******,iocharset=utf8,rw,context=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

Comment: Tons of, but first you might want to check that your apache server can access the files by checking the permissions of the files and directories.

Comment: Yes all users have rw- access in the directory.

Comment: Try adding this option when you mount that directory. Sounds like selinux issues... ,context=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0